# however vs. how

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. How cold it is, he leaves the window open all night.
> 2. However cold it is, he leaves the window open all night.

Could you tell me which sentence is more polished or natural? Or is there any difference between them?

Comment: It seems to me that your 1st example is unacceptable. Your 2nd example is somewhat okay, though I'd probably prefer something more like: 2b. _"**However** cold it is, he **always** leaves the window open all night."_

Comment: Though, with some punctuation changes, your 1st example could work as an exclamative: _"How cold it is! He leaves the window open all night."_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Idiomatically, OP's first version is *totally* unacceptable, but I have to say I don't think the second version is the most "natural" usage either. Consider this from Google Books...

> *I get [up early however late](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22celibating%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22up%20early%20however%20late%22&tbm=bks) I go to bed* (no written instances at all)
>    *I get [up early **no matter how** late](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22celibating%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22up%20early%20no%20matter%20how%20late%22&tbm=bks) I go to bed*( (56 written instances)

---

To my mind, the "core" sense of ***however*** is *by whatever **means***, where at least there's an obvious connection between *how* and *means, method, way*. But in OP's usage, it means *to whatever **extent*** - which although not uncommon in casual speech, strikes me as being at least *slightly* "odd".

---

EDIT: I'm guessing some people have downvoted this answer because they "know" that native Anglophones often use ***However much*** rather than ***No matter how much***. That's quite true, but as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=No%20matter%20how%20much%20you%2CHowever%20much%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNo%20matter%20how%20much%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHowever%20much%20you%3B%2Cc0) shows, usage has shifted significantly over the past half-century...

[image]

Comment: +1 The first sentence just isn't right, however, I don't see any problems in the second sentence. However much you dislike _However_ at the start of a sentence, meaning _to whatever extent_ might be because it is often found at the end of the sentence, but there's no reason not to put it at the start, however odd it seems. :)

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference whether the [relative?] clause is moved to the front or not. *However*, I do think your comment implies I have a greater "dislike" of such usages than is actually the case. The reason I find *no matter how* more "natural" than *however* in such constrictions is primarily that it's far more common - as evidenced by those Google Books results, which I think show that my reaction reflects *average* usage. I only really added the "slightly odd" bit to suggest there might be some "logic" to my/average preference.

Comment: No matter however cold it is. what about this version?

Comment: @nima_persian: I don't understand all the downvotes here. Both *no matter how* and *however* are perfectly acceptable (although the former is far more common in your exact context). To me at least, mixing *both* forms is "not acceptable". But obviously some people have different ideas about the two basic choices, so perhaps they also find the "hybrid" version okay too. I think maybe this question needs a bounty to get some more attention from competent speakers, since most of the votes just seem plain *wrong* (and there are few explanatory comments).

Comment: so I am not the only one who is misjudged here. Even thought the answer is correct some can downvote with some made up reason. ELL got many problems or a certain lack of commenting with reason. :)

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: You've inspired my to try and breathe fresh life into this answer with a supporting NGram usage chart! Whether that'll attract any more counterbalancing upvotes remains to be seen.

Answer (score -2):

The second one seems more natural to me. The first one, with a little change in syntax, would be fine. But that's just me!

The second sentence is fine because the word *however* is used with an adjective expressing the degree of coldness. It simply means the degree of coldness does not matter. He keeps the window open.

A simpler example -

> *however long it takes, finish it.*

[[Courtesy TheFreeDictionary]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32514/however-vs-how/32519#32519)

The first sentence, as I said needs some change. I'd write it this way...

> He leaves the window open all night, no matter how cold it is (outside). Or no matter how cold it is, he . . .

Comment: So, do you always use how together with an adjective or adverb, as my first sentence doesn't work well?

Comment: -1 because I do *not* think OP's first example is "okay".

Comment: nearly -1 from me too. The first sentence needs an extra word or two _No matter_ at the start would be enough to sort it, but as it stands, it's understandable but just not the way people say it. It's the 'both seem Okay' that's the problem - take that out and it'll improve the answer.

Comment: @Frank I also thought the same way and thus was reluctant to put the sentence as it is in my answer. Anyway corrected now.